How do I get the number of rows that satisfy a condition?
If there's a matrix like this:
[20,39,50,80,21;
 40,79,80,65, 5;
 20,15,60,45,21;
 10,60,20,35,70];

How do I calculate the number of rows that have three or more elements which are less than 50?

Thank you for editing your title, it's much better now. Please post the code you've written so far and point out where it's failing to meet your requirements.


Start with array: A
Check if elements are less than 50: b = A < 50
Number of columns per row where b is true: sum(b,2)
Number of rows where the above is 3 or more nnz(sum(b,2) >= 3)

All together:
numRowsWith3OrMoreValsUnder50 = nnz( sum(A<50, 2) >= 3 );

